# The log reported build Impala success! but it stopped at 92%

Tags: build, impala

[image: 1]

```
14:16:50 [INFO] Tests are skipped.
14:16:50 [INFO] Tests are skipped.
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala Parent POM 4.3.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SUCCESS [  7.434 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Test Data Generator ................................ SUCCESS [03:03 min]  
14:16:50 [INFO] impala-minimal-s3a-aws-sdk ......................... SUCCESS [01:37 min]  
14:16:50 [INFO] impala-minimal-hive-exec ........................... SUCCESS [05:16 min]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Impala Executor Dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [02:29 min]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala External Data Source ................. SUCCESS [  0.009 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala External Data Source API ............. SUCCESS [ 13.566 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala External Data Source Sample .......... SUCCESS [  0.054 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala External Data Source Test Library .... SUCCESS [  0.050 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala Query Event Hook API ................. SUCCESS [  0.025 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] YARN Extras ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.211 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Apache Impala Query Engine Frontend ................ SUCCESS [08:39 min]  
14:16:50 [INFO] Impala Nested Table Flattener ...................... SUCCESS [ 20.542 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] test-hive-udfs 1.0 ................................. SUCCESS [  3.012 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] test-corrupt-hive-udfs 1.0 ......................... SUCCESS [  0.013 s]  
14:16:50 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS  
[ 92%] Built target java  
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/notests_all_targets.dir/rule] error 2  
make: *** [notests_all_targets] error 2
```

Did I succeed? What is the impact on future use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built target java % might have been reported incorrectly. Try running the same command again and check if results are the same.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a few times, a little at a time, but finally I got it